# What is the difference between comma and period between two independent clauses?

Tags: punctuation

What is the difference between "I ate a banana, and I ate an apple" and "I ate a banana. I ate an apple"?

for me it feels like they have a different meaning like the first one is ordered, it says that I ate a banana and then after that I ate an apple but in the second one you don't know the order like you may have eaten an apple then a banana or vice versa, is this right and are there other differences?

Comment: It would not be at all natural to express this as two separate sentences, unless the writer was trying to achieve a particular effect - nor to repeat 'I ate'. The normal way to say it would be "I ate a banana and [then] an apple."

Comment: What is the difference between their meaning? is both of them coherent as each other? what do you mean by "not be at all natural" what is "natural"? what is "a particular effect"?

Comment: No-one, in ordinary conversation or writing, would express that as two separate sentences. The only context in which I can imagine it being used is, for example, in a story where someone is having a long, boring wait for something, and the writer might use short sentences to show their boredom. "I ate a banana. I ate an apple. I looked at my watch. I got up and looked out of the window." etc. etc.

Comment: Well what is the difference between them in meaning and why wouldn't they use them in conversation or writing?

Comment: There is no 'difference in meaning', but people just don't talk like that. A native speaker would say "I ate a banana and an apple", as I have already told you.